# How to show CircularProgressBar when initState loads data?

Tags: flutter

I want to show a `CircularProgressBar` when the `initState` method loads data before I navigate to `HomePage`.
My Code:

```
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Provider.of<Example1ListViewModel>(context, listen: false).list1();
        Provider.of<Example2ListViewModel>(context, listen: false)
            .list2();
        Provider.of<Example3ListViewModel>(context, listen: false)
            .list3();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return HomePage();
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
 final bool isLoading = true;
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Provider.of<Example1ListViewModel>(context, listen: false).list1();
        Provider.of<Example2ListViewModel>(context, listen: false)
            .list2();
        Provider.of<Example3ListViewModel>(context, listen: false)
            .list3();
         // This callback function will be called when initstate completes
         WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) => isLoading = false);
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return isLoading
              ? const Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()) 
              : HomePage();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default display ProgressIndicator, and after data loaded display HomePage(). Use FutureBuilder or add in your model state variable bool isLoading.